# python -c 'import time; while True: time.sleep(5)' fails with syntax error

Tags: bash, python-3.x

In my bash Terminal (Mac OS) I type the following:

```
python -c 'import time; while True: time.sleep(5)'
```

And a SyntaxError is thrown.

Why should this be? Both of the following examples run:

```
python -c 'import time; time.sleep(5)'
python -c 'while True: pass'
```

so not sure why this is throwing an error.

Comment: (As far as I can tell,) Python won't allow two or more colons (":") on one physical code line.  It will allow a colon to be on the same line as one or more semicolons (";"), as long as the colon occurs first, before any of the semicolons.